# Capture from camera, from stream, merge and broadcast on a webpage

Tags: video-streaming, processing, quartz-graphics

I'm currently working for a project called God is a DJ, which will be presented both at biennale of Montreal, and Mapping festival of geneva, 11th, 12th, 18th and 19th of mai. The company insan-ë is interested in bringing technologies into performing arts, and doing a show with one scene in Montréal, and another one in Geneva, CH. You can check it if you're interested. The application used streaming videos from one place to the other via scenic, and video composition and mapping will be done in mixologic, both applications developed at the SAT in Montréal. I do the more basic developing, MIDI interfaces, machine set-up, and this here.. 
We want to stream the whole thing online, with an independent camera in each theater.

**Question:**

The application I need to build would do the following(it's quite straight-forward, actually):
Get a stream from Montréal, capture from a camera, put both images side-by-side(control over latency would be a great option), mix the sound, and stream this to be viewed by visiting a webpage.
I first thought of doing this via JAVA and Processing(mostly because i want to do a little more processing, and i'm not too fond of visual programming), but I guess qc might be the best option. however, I find documentation on qc quite poor, so far. I also thought of Threenodes.js, because it might be easier

Anyways, I would really appreciate if you would point me in the right direction for this. I'm not such an experienced programer, and I think of too many possibilities, without knowing the capacities or limits of each of them.

Any suggestion is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a web page in simple HTML with two video player components placed side by side (either using the ["video" tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp) or other player through an "object" tag), one playing the stream from Montreal and the other playing the stream from the locally captured video. The Montreal part is probably already using a streaming server so you could use the same for your local stream, or try [something like VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html)

When the page is loaded, the two players will start streaming independently and their audio will be mixed normally by the operating system. The user will also be able to control volume through the volume sliders of each video player. (No latency control in this case i am afraid :-( except of course having delay hardware between the local camera and the frame grabber)

If you would now like to process the two streams and show the processed stream it will be a bit more convoluted because you would have to write a program that contains two player objects with the ability to triger an event on every frame they decode (and that's not the problem, you can find such components easily in any language).

Within that handler you can obtain the image and sound streams, do your processing and create the mixed frames which would now have to be encoded and sent across the network as a stream. This last part is not straightforward. The easiest way to get around this would be to have your application go full screen and draw whatever it is that it draws on your computer's main screen. You can now take this output from your graphics card and pass it as input to your frame grabber. You can then setup the video stream server (VLC for example, as above) to broadcast this input of the frame grabber.

You can now access this combined video through a player inside an HTML page as explained above.

With this solution you can control of course everything (including latency) from your code...

As far as Processing.org is concerned, please have a look at http://processing.org/reference/libraries/video/index.html for components to decode video streams

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is more or less what I had in mind. However, control over latency is mandatory, unfortunately..

So what I plan is the following, and I hope it will work:
-have one app in MTL stream to GVA(either via JAVA sendbitstream, or save to file)
-have an app in GVA capturing from livecam and stream/file from MTL
(both these apps would be written in processing and JAVA)
-use Syphon to have processing send to VLC
-have VLC stream the whole things online

questions:
translate bitstream back to PImage?
VLC multicasting limits?

Comment: About bitstream, are you thinking about streaming uncompressed video? Because this is probably the easiest way to switch back and forth to PImage to use functions that can handle that object. As far as multicast is concerned, you are up to the limitations of the protocol (IP-Multicast). Did you have something more specific in mind?

Comment: Well, would uncompressed video not be too much for the network(especially it'll be already quite loaded by the rest of the show..) I have nothing in mind, really, i need to come up with a tool that would allow this, no limitations, no rules, just needs to work :)